# Optimize MySQL query nested not exists possible?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have list of submissions of exercises done by students who are part of a group(classroom), this contains:

```
 submission table: userId, groupId, exercise_id (and more irrelevant data)
 users table: userId, groupId
```

I want to select all the exercises done by all the students in a specific group. For this I currently have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(exercise_id) FROM submissions as c1 WHERE c1.groupId = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT DISTINCT(UserId) FROM users as u WHERE u.GroupId = 1 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT exercise_id FROM submissions as c2 WHERE u.UserId = c2.UserId 
        AND c2.exercise_id = c1.exercise_id
    )
)
```

i.e. I select all the exercises for which there are no users in the group that have not done the exercise.

However, this query takes 5 seconds on a submission table with 1.5 million rows. Which steps could I take to further optimise this query? I have considered inner joins, but won't this result in the same query execution plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `groupid` really shouldn't be in both tables.  Assuming the values are consistent, try the following:

```
select s.exercise_id
from submissions s
where s.groupid = 1
group by s.exercise_id
having count(distinct userid) = (select count(distinct userid) from users where groupid = 1);
```

For performance, you want an index on `submissions(groupid, exercise_id)`.  Also, if you know there are no duplicate submissions or users, then remove the `distinct`, because that has an adverse effect on performance.

Comment: This works blazingly fast compared to my query. Is there a structured way you came up with it?

Comment: @Bas . . . Your problem is a type of "set-within-sets" query, and I generally approach these using aggregation and a `having` clause (I should note:  note always, but usually).